# Failing to install flutterwave with composer

Tags: laravel, flutterwave

Good day, i am trying to install flutterwave in my laravel project 9.0 and i have followed the instruction on the Github section https://github.com/kingflamez/laravelrave of flutterwave but i keep getting the following errors

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires kingflamez/laravelrave ^4.2 -> satisfiable by kingflamez/laravelrave[v4.2.0].
- kingflamez/laravelrave v4.2.0 requires illuminate/support ^5.0|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require kingflamez/laravelrave:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require kingflamez/laravelrave:^2.1" if you know which you need.

i have tried to change my composer.json but still no success.

"require": {
"php": "^7.2|^8.0.2",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3|^7.0.1|^7.2",
"illuminate/support": "^5.0|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.21",
"laravel/framework": "^9.11",
"laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
"laravel/socialite": "^5.5",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
"livewire/livewire": "^2.10",
"socialiteproviders/apple": "^5.2",
"socialiteproviders/facebook": "^4.1",
"socialiteproviders/google": "^4.1",

```
    "kingflamez/laravelrave": "^4.2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/breeze": "^1.9",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
},
```

Comment: You can try this `composer require "kingflamez/laravelrave" --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 0):

the package is not updated to work with laravel 9 for now. I am having the same issue. i will try and raise the issue soon